# facebook links image

Tags: html, css

When i paste a link to my website i would like facebook to grab certain images from my website to show. How do i do this?

i tried adding this right below my title tag but it doesnt seem to work, nothing shows

```
<link rel='image_src' type='image/jpeg' href='http://www.url.com/myImage.png'>
```

regards,
alexander

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the facebook "Open Graph" meta data protocol.

`<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.url.com/myImage.png" />`

[Full Documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/)